# Determine the closest free set of X/Y coordinates within an ever expanding 2D grid stored in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a very basic MySQL table in which X and Y coordinates are stored for tiles within a grid. The center of the grid is 0,0 and tiles can be created in any direction. If the coordinates exists in the MySQL table, they are considered "taken".

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| tile_id | position_x | position_y |
+---------+------------+------------+
|       1 |          0 |          0 |
|       2 |          1 |          0 |
|       3 |          0 |          1 |
|       4 |          1 |          1 |
|       5 |         -1 |         -1 |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

I need to place a set of 4 tiles (as a square, not a rectangle) into the grid in the closest possible position to 0,0.

To illustrate - the green tiles below would need to be found.

[image]

Manhattan distance is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: This doesn't look like a database administration problem. If the table is not too large, load it into a memory array and solve it there.

Comment: And if the table is large (millions of records)?

Comment: Once you have found a mathematical algorithm, we can discuss whether or how to best implement in a database.